multiple anchor links to multiple detail tags from different page
I have a list of items (competitions, each with date) on my front page and would like to link them to the more detailed list of these competitions on a different page via anchor links. they all have different ids - how do I do that?
the items on the front page look like this - I already tried to inlude the id in the link:
<a href="mydomain.at/turnierkalender#1530">Landesmeisterschaft Latein Wien | 07.09.2024</a>

the second page (mydomain.at/turnierkalender) has multiple entries - the corresponding one being:
<details class="turnier" id="1375" open="">
  <summary>
    <span class="date">07.09.2024</span>
    <span class="title">Landesmeisterschaft Latein Wien<br>...
  </summary>
  <div class="more-data" id="more-1375">
  <div class="more-details"> ...
  </div>
  </div>  
</details>

The link works fine, it just doesn't open the tag - obviously.
is there a simple way to make the tag open on click?
All the answered questions refer to just one link not so many different ones.

The :target pseudo class would apply to the details element in this situation - but I don't know if there is a cross-browser way to show it as "opened" by manipulating CSS properties only. Plus, I could imagine that it might be bad in terms of accessibility. So this should rather be done using JavaScript. On page load, check if there is a URL fragment, and if so, if it is "pointing" to a details element. If that is the case, then set the open property of the element to true.

Depending on how your pages are served - if building the HTML server-side (eg [tag:asp.net-mvc]) then the action could check for the URL fragment and output open='true' when rendering.
